# CSS использование opacity

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, opacity

Вот примерно то что имею:

```css
#top{
        background-color: white;
        height: 200px;
        /*border: 2px solid black;*/
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
#show span{
       position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        left: 20px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div id="top">
    <div id="show">
        <span>Menu</span>
        <div id="menu">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Find as</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Chat as</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
             </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Почему текст в блоке `<span>` остается прозрачным?

Comment: Потому что весь top прозрачный, а span является неотъемлемой частью top. Если вам нужен прозрачный фон — делайте прозрачный фон, а не opacity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что в CSS прозрачность дочернего элемента HTML не может быть больше прозрачности родительского элемента. То есть прозрачность show не может быть больше прозрачности top - 0.7.
Для решения Вашей проблемы можно создать внутри top еще один div, который не будет родительским элементом для show. С помощью абсолютного позиционирования выставляем как фон top, указывая ему нужные размеры, и с помощью z-index помещаем его под show. Не забывайте, что z-index работает только при прописанном позиционировании.

Вот код решения:

```
#top{
        height: 200px;
}
#show span{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 1;
}
#show {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 1;
}
#background_for_top{
    background-color: gray;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 0;
}
<div id="top">
    <div id="background_for_top"></div>
    <div id="show">
        <span>Menu</span>
        <div id="menu">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Find as</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Chat as</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
             </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделай прозрачность только для background так:

```css
#top{
        background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        height: 200px;
        /*border: 2px solid black;*/
    }
#show span{
       position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        left: 20px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div id="top">
    <div id="show">
        <span>Menu</span>
        <div id="menu">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Find as</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Chat as</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
             </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!