# Прозрачность div

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать что бы span не подвергался opacity и был белым а не серым.

```html
<div style="height:50px;background:black;opacity:0.8">
<span style="color:white;">Текст</span>
</div>
```

Comment: И этот дубликат: и [CSS использование opacity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/922722/262779)

Comment: всё , что находится внутри элемента, которому вы задаете opacity - будет распространяться на всех его потомков.